# How to create objects which can be assigned any type in c++

Tags: c++

I have a class definition like this:

```
class Paint{
 AnyType* Color;
};
```

what I want to do is to create a class (AnyType) whose object can be assigned any object of any class type. like so:

```
class Blue{}; 
class Green {};`

Paint MyPaint;
MyPaint.Color = new Green();
// color gets changed
MyPaint.Color = new Blue();
```

how do I declare AnyType?

```
Class AnyType{
//class definition
};
```

Comment: So you want a `void*`?

Comment: The answer to the question literally as asked is `void*` but it does not seem that the question correctly identified the requirement.  Instead, I think you really wanted `Green` and `Blue` to be derived from some common base type.

Comment: @JSF agree.  I just was not sure if they just want color objects or any object possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Paint{
 BaseColor* Color;
};

class BaseColor {}

class Blue : BaseColor {}; 
class Green : BaseColor {};`

Paint MyPaint;
MyPaint.Color = new Green();
// color gets changed
MyPaint.Color = new Blue();
```

Answer (score 1):

The pure C++ standard way to do this, would be to [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) back and forth from a [`void*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530080/what-is-a-void-pointer-in-c). This will, however, require you to know the correct type to cast back from later on.

If you are open to 3rd party solutions, this is one such application for [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/any.html).

That being said, there are very few times when something like this is a good idea. There are often better designs to solve your problem. Frankly when someone wants to do something like this it is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and their *actual* problem can be solved in a more robust way.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Color` member should probably be of some `ColorType` type. And classes `Green` and `Blue` should be derived from `ColorType`.

Please see rbaghbanli's code which does exactly this (accepted answer).

Then you can put all aspects shared by classes Green and Blue into ColorType, which is quite useful.

If you user a `void*` or `boost::any` there is nothing you can really do with this pointer, as C++ forgets what it is actually pointing to.

Background: C++ is completely statically typed and does not allow introspection. The only available runtime mechanism is virtual functions, and this mechanism is quite limited.

If you really need something which can be any type, you have to write it yourself. But I assume you do not really need this. I assume you need `Can be any of a kind.` and this is well enough supported in C++ through derivation.

Comment: can u please show me how to declare a can be of any kind variable?

Comment: I did not write about 'can be of any kind'. I wrote about 'can be any of a kind', for example, 'can be any color'. See the accepted answer, this shows how to do this.