# Function with void *a and pointer function as parameter

Tags: c

I am new to C and pointers (so please go easy on me).
I am using a reference book, and I came across these code with no explanations whatsoever (all it said was: a function name is a pointer to that function):

```
int isBigger(void *a,void *b,int (*f)(void *,void *)){
   return f(a,b)
}
```

My questions are:

1. What is void *a?
2. Is *f a pointer to a function?
3. What is void *? Is it related to void *a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the code snippet given would not compile, I assume this is what you meant:

```
int isBigger(void *a,void *b,int (*f)(void *,void *)){
   return f(a,b);
}
```

`void*` is a pointer that can point to anything. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530080/what-is-a-void-pointer-in-c) for more information.

`f` is a pointer to a function that takes two `void*` and returns an `int`. You can invoke the function with `f(a,b)`. You can find more examples in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work).