# Why can I use static_cast With void* but not With char*

Tags: c++, casting, reinterpret-cast, strict-aliasing, static-cast

I know that [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) is primarily used going to or from a `char*`.

But I was surprised to find that [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) could do the same with a `void*`. For example:

```
auto foo "hello world"s;
auto temp = static_cast<void*>(&foo);
auto bar = static_cast<string*>(temp);
```

What do we gain from using `reinterpret_cast` and `char*` over `static_cast` and `void*`? Is it something to do with the strict aliasing problem?

Comment: Generally you cast to a `char*` do do something with the individual bytes.  You cannot do that with a `void*`.

Comment: @NathanOliver So you're saying like `memcpy` or similar?

Comment: Well `memcpy` is one of them.  The `read` and `wrtie` function of streams are others.  If you need to send stuff over com data you would also do this.

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess the point here is that `void*` is a considered in the hierarchy of any type while a `char*` is not? That's the reason this `static_cast` is allowed? But then I guess at the end of the day, the answer to my question is none of the std library functions are looking for a `void*` so why would I even use this type.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Can you point me to a section in that answer which answers the question: "What do we gain from using `reinterpret_cast` and `char*` over `static_cast` and `void*`?" Perhaps I'm missing it, but I really don't see it.

Comment: Reopened. This is not about which cast to use; it's about the peculiar behavior of `void*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question really has 2 parts:

1. Should I use `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` to work with a pointer to the underlying bit pattern of an object without concern for the object type?
2. If I should use `reinterpret_cast` is a `void*` or a `char*` preferable to address this underlying bit pattern?

> [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast): Converts between types using a combination of implicit and user-defined conversions

In 5.2.9[expr.static.cast]13 the standard, in fact, gives the example:

```
T* p1 = new T;
const T* p2 = static_cast<const T*>(static_cast<void*>(p1));
```

It leverages the implicit cast:

> A prvalue pointer to any (optionally cv-qualified) object type `T` can be converted to a prvalue pointer to (identically cv-qualified) `void`. The resulting pointer represents the same location in memory as the original pointer value. If the original pointer is a null pointer value, the result is a null pointer value of the destination type.<sup>[*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Pointer_conversions)</sup>

There is however no implicit cast from a pointer of type `T` to a `char*`. So the only way to accomplish that cast is with a `reinterpret_cast`.

> [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast): Converts between types by reinterpreting the underlying bit pattern

So in answer to part **1** of your question when you cast to a `void*` or a `char*` you are looking to work with the underlying bit pattern, **`reinterpret_cast` should be used because it's use denotes to the reader a conversion to/from the underlying bit pattern.**

Next let's compare `void*` to `char*`. The decision between these two may be a bit more application dependent. If you are going to use a standard library function with your underlying bit pattern just use the type that function accepts:

- `void*` is used in the `mem` functions provided in the `cstring` library
- [`read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) and [`write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) use `char*` as inputs

It's notable that C++ specific libraries prefer `char*` for pointing to memory.
Holding onto memory as a `void*` seems to have been preserved for compatibility reasons as pointer out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8530111/2642059). So if a `cstring` library function won't be used on your underlying bit patern, use the C++ specific libraries behavior to answer part **2** of your question: **Prefer `char*` to `void*`.**

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, `static_cast` will do cast any two types if one of them can be cast to the other *implicitly*. That includes arithmetic casts, down-casts, up-casts and cast to and from `void*`.

That is, if this cast is valid:

```
void foo(A a);
B b;
foo(b);
```

Then the both `static_cast<B>(a)` and `static_cast<A>(b)` will also be valid.

Since any pointer can be cast implicitly to `void*`, thus your peculiar behavior.

`reinterpret_cast` do cast by reinterpreting the bit-pattern of the values. That, as you said in the question, is usually done to convert between unrelated pointer types.

Yes, you can convert between unrelated pointer types through `void*`, by using two `static_cast`:

```
B *b;
A *a1 = static_cast<A*>(b); //compiler error
A *a2 = static_cast<A*>(static_cast<void*>(b)); //it works (evil laugh)!
```

But that is bending the rules. Just use `reinterpret_cast` if you really need this.