# return type of void* in c++

Tags: c++, linux, void, void-pointers, return-type

Can I declare a return type of `void *` for a c++ function? I am working in the Linux environment and I want to return a `void *` for library handle in case of `dlopen` for shared library.

Comment: This is a programming question, more suitable for stackoverflow (unrelated to linux). But it's also badly asked: what exactly do you have to do and what do you already have? You can always cast the returned value, or write a wrapper.

Comment: yes  but  am  confused  that   i  am  dealing  with  void * type is it  not  equivalent void .Can i just  directly  return void *

Comment: actually   my main  purpose  is  to decalre  the  dlopen handle of shared  libraryin a function and just  reuse  it  so  i want  to  return the  void *   in that  function   so that i can  fetch the  result from dlopen and  just  use it inoutside

Comment: Yes, you can return a `void *`, though it's not very nice C++. As for C, there are a bunch of standard C library functions that return a `void *` (e.g. `malloc()` and `memcpy()`). But I'm not really sure what you actually want to do, so it might be worth trying to elaborate on that (after this gets migrated to SE).

Comment: actually  the  thing  is the  result of  dlopen  is  stored  in  type  void *  so  i  want to  define  that only one  time  in  a  function and  then reuse it  in apprpriate   places by  just  fetching  the return  value

Comment: A `void*` is a valid type for a return. The C++ preferred raw pointer type is `char*`, you can read more about that in the last paragraph of this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/39648025/2642059 Fundamentally in C++ if you're working with a raw pointer, you should get it into a type as quickly as possible so you don't damage performance and so you can take advantage of templating.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I declare a return type of void * for a c++ function?

Yes, you can. It's one way to return an opaque pointer.
Another would be:

```
struct Foo;
Foo* bar();
```