# Function declarations with * in front and void returning values?

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

So, I'm reading Beej's Guide to Network Programming, and he uses this function:

```
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
    return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
}
```

So, I get what its doing in general. What I'm having trouble understanding is what exactly the * in the function declaration is doing. Also, this function seems to be returning a memory location, but its void. Whats going on here?

Comment: Does it help if I write it like this: `void* get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)`

Comment: This has the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334831/what-is-a-void-pointer-and-what-is-a-null-pointer

Comment: Not being funny, but network programming is going to be pretty tough without having a basic understanding of C.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I hear ya. I actually do have a fairly good understanding of C/C++, its just I've never come across this syntax before. I know I have holes in my knowledge, but hey, I'm in school. Now is the time to fill in the gaps, not say "Oh, I don't know about this, so I shouldn't even try." I appreciate your input, none the less.

Comment: @Nick: OK. Pointers are really, really fundamental to C. Good luck with your studies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The '*' means that the function is returning a void *.  This is a pointer which can be cast to any other pointer.